# Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator for EasyRepro

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, easyrepro

Whenever I try to run the EasyRepro test cases, I run into the error "Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator". People are saying to  set the useAutomationExtension capability to false. However I don't know where I would add the following line of code in EasyRepro:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error message by adding this line of code inside BroswerOptions.cs

```
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```